# How do I find an enum value given the arguments that were supplied to its constructor?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum class like this:

```
public enum Position {
    A1(0,0),
    A2(1,0),
    //etc

    public final int dy, dx;

    private Position(int dy, int dx) {
        this.dy = dy;
        this.dx = dx;
    }
}
```

Now I want a method: `public static Position getPosition(int dx, int dy)`
Can I return `Position.A1` or `Position.A2` with the given `dx` and `dy` without using a whole lot of if-structures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way (and actually relatively fast) to do it is by simply looping through the enums:

```
public static Position getPosition(int dx, int dy) {
    for (Position position : values()) {
        if (position.dx == dx && position.dy == dy) {
            return position;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the enums in a `Map` (local to the enum class) as you create them. Populate the map with the key made up of the coordinates, and the value being the enum itself.

Then your `getPosition()` method will use the coordinates as a key to the stored value (enum). That may be faster than iterating through the set of enums (as usual it depends on the number of positions created)

A *trivial* way to generate the key would be something like

```
String key = "" + dx + "/" + dy;
```

(note: since the map is static to the class, it's a shared resource and you may want to worry about synchronisation etc. in a threaded environment)

Comment: That is a really bad way to create a key. Many times I've seen this sort of thing done, even when the key components could contain the separators.

Comment: Well spotted. Done in haste. Now changed to actually work :-)